# Reinstalled High Sierra: System now extremely slow and unresponsive

Tags: high-sierra

In attempting to solve another problem, I've tried to reinstall macOS High Sierra onto my Mac mini (2011). Everything seemed to go fine with the install, however after booting up it is now extremely slow. Every action I take requires a beachball, every button I press in any application, including clicking the red X button to close a window will cause the machine to lock up for a few seconds. Any application I try to launch bounces on the dock for 15-30 seconds. They system is basically unusable, and won't respond to any of my attempts to connect to its file shares, which means I cannot access any of my documents, which has me very stressed out. (This Mac's primary job is to host files from its internal drive, which I connect to with my MacBook).

Some additional notes:

- There are no processes consuming the CPU
- There are no processes using up all the memory
- The OS is on an internal SSD which is performing fine.
- This behavior is not limited to GUI apps, entering terminal commands, even ssh'd in from a different machine frequently locks the machine up
- I am using Remote Desktop to control this machine and every minute or so it completely locks up and enters the "Reconnecting..." phase for some time. Seems like this is only getting worse.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with that version of macOS.
It's internally doing a bunch of stuff, the solution is to simply wait.
So for example if you have errands to run or something make sure sleep is set to off and leave the Mac running.  It'll come back to normal soon.  On my old iMac it probably took half a day but that didn't have an SSD so yours should be faster.

Comment: I wish this were true, but, as I said in my original post, there's nothing using the CPU, not even Spotlight. I've also never seen spotlight or any other macOS process for that matter use so many resources as to leave the system in an unusable state.

Comment: Yes you will not see anything obviously using the CPU.  It's exactly what happened on my machine and it resolves itself eventually every time after I clean install, just like in my answer.